# Require authentication for entire Blazor Server app

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I'm trying to add a custom authentication for my Blazor Server app and I can't get it to redirect an unauthorized user to the login page.

I've already tried this:

This is my **app.razor** component

```html
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <RedirectToLogin />
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>No encontrado</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Dirección inválida.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

This is my RedirectToLogin component

```
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        NavManager.NavigateTo("/login", forceLoad: true);
    }
}
```

But it seems the `<NotAuthorized>` section is never reached as I set a breakpoint on the `OnInitializedAsync` method and the debugging never stopped.

I'm using cookies for authentication and it works as I added an `<AuthorizeView>` tag in my MainLayout to test it showing a text for not authenticated users.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get it to work, I was missing an `[Authorize]` attribute.

I put `@attribute [Authorize]` right after my `@using` directives at my `_Imports.razor` file and the `<NotAuthorized>` tag under the Router was finally reached, and I just simply removed the RedirectToLogin component to render the Login one directly.

Also, as I used `[Authorize]` at that level, I had to add `@attribute [AllowAnonymous]` on my login component

Therefore, leaving my Router like this:

```html
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <Login />
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>No encontrado</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Dirección inválida.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

And my MainLayout like this:

```html
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        @*Normal layout when authorized*@
        @Body
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        @Body
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

The Login component is just a form with username and password fields

Answer (score 0):

> Combines the behaviors of AuthorizeView and RouteView, so that it
> displays the page matching the specified route **but only if the user is
> authorized to see it**. 
> This from Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.authorization.authorizerouteview?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

**You can try:** 
1- Keep you `AuthorizeRouteView` sample like this: 
`<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)"/>` 
2- Wrap your `RedirectToLogin` component with:

```
<AuthorizeView>
  <NotAuthorized>
     //something
  </NotAuthorized>
  <Authorized>
    //something
  </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I put my AuthorizeView in my MainLayout, so that I could have the menu displayed wether the user was authenticated or not, and it worked there, my problem was with the redirect, I could get it to work at the end of the day, I was missing an [Authorize] attribute